# How to use ADODB parameterized query with adArray data type in VBScript?

Tags: sql, scripting, vbscript, adodb

I have not been able to find an example of how to use this anywhere. I am trying to do a simple SELECT statement with a parameterized query. I want to use the adArray data type. Here is an example

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ?"
set objCmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
set objParam = objCmd.Createparameter("@id", 0x2000, 1, length, arrMyArray)

objCmd.Parameters.Append objParam
```

This throws a wrong type error. I was curious if anyone has ever gotten this to work or has any examples. That'd be great.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: I left out all the connection and recordset and actually executing the command.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea which database providers will support arrays.

What I prefer to do is pass the array as a single long string, then use a UDF called Split(). The result is something like this:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (Split(?))"
set objCmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
myBigString = ConvertArrayToCSV(arrMyArray) ' you have to write this, of course
set objParam = objCmd.Createparameter("@id", 200, 1, length, myBigString)

objCmd.Parameters.Append objParam
```

[Here's a discussion of the Split() concept.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182668/how-to-split-comma-separated-text-in-mysql-stored-procedure)

**Edit**

I corrected the above (the parameter type is 200, not 0x2000), and I also now see that ADO appears to support this syntax:

```
0x2000 OR 129 ' array of strings
0x2000 OR 200 ' array of varchar
```

But I haven't tested this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This may be a dumb question, but how exactly am I supposed to tell the objParam that it's an array of string type. The documentation says this:
`Combine with another data type to indicate that the other data type is an array`
How do I do that with the 0x2000

Comment: I'm pretty sure that although it's included in the documentation it isn't support by ADO and was added for future compatibility.

Comment: More info from Lankymart on the adArray type being unimplemented: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35453499/1026