# MYSQL join comma separated query

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have searched around and came up with nothing.

I have 2 tables and to not have to query the database for every post that shows i need to join them somehow.

I want to get the `url` from the pics table that have the id of the `pics` field in posts table. Now heres my problem: the `pics` field is a commma separated "list" (4,1 or 32,4,32,2), because every post usually have more than one picture.

Table set ups:

posts:

```
 id | header | text | pics
| 1     xxx     xxx    3,1     
| 2     xxx     xxx    2,10,4     
| 3     xxx     xxx    16,17,18,19     
| 4     xxx     xxx    11,12,13
```

pics:

```
id | name | url
| 1   xxx   xxx    
| 2   xxx   xxx        
| 3   xxx   xxx          
| 4   xxx   xxx          
| 10  xxx   xxx         
| 11  xxx   xxx         
| 12  xxx   xxx                  
| 13  xxx   xxx          
| 16  xxx   xxx          
| 17  xxx   xxx        
| 18  xxx   xxx
```

Comment: Why are you storing a comma separate list that you need to join on?  Please normalize that table structure.

Comment: step 1: redesign the table so it's properly normalized. step 2) after normalization, use a plain regular JOIN query.

Comment: That `pics` CSV list could do with being a separate table, normalise the data.  If pics only ever appear for a single post, adding a `post_id` key to the `pics` table would suffice.

Comment: Also there are many similar questions to this. eg. [Can you split/explode a field in a MySQL query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471914/can-you-split-explode-a-field-in-a-mysql-query) [How to split comma separated text in MySQL stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182668/how-to-split-comma-separated-text-in-mysql-stored-procedure), etc...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I **strongly advise that you fix your current database structure** so you are not storing the data in a comma separated list. You should structure your tables similar to the following:

```
CREATE TABLE posts
    (`id` int, `header` varchar(3), `text` varchar(3))
;

CREATE TABLE pics
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(3), `url` varchar(3))
;

CREATE TABLE post_pics
    (`post_id` int, `pic_id` int)
;
```

Then you can easily get a result by joining the tables:

```
select p.id,
  p.header,
  p.text,
  c.name,
  c.url
from posts p
inner join post_pics pp
  on p.id = pp.post_id
inner join pics c
  on pp.pic_id = c.id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26178/2).

*If* you cannot alter your table, then you should be able to query using `FIND_IN_SET`:

```
select p.id, p.header, p.text, p.pics,
  c.id c_id, c.name, c.url
from posts p
inner join pics c
  on find_in_set(c.id, p.pics)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75857/2).

Edit, if you want the data displayed as a comma-separated list then you can use `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Query 1:

```
select p.id,
  p.header,
  p.text,
  group_concat(c.name separator ', ') name,
  group_concat(c.url separator ', ') url
from posts p
inner join post_pics pp
  on p.id = pp.post_id
inner join pics c
  on pp.pic_id = c.id
group by p.id, p.header, p.text;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26178/3)

Query 2:

```
select p.id, p.header, p.text, p.pics,
  group_concat(c.name separator ', ') name,
  group_concat(c.url separator ', ') url
from posts p
inner join pics c
  on find_in_set(c.id, p.pics)
group by p.id, p.header, p.text, p.pics;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75857/3)

Comment: Thank you for your quick respons, but in both cases it returns ALL (header, text, url etc) onces per picture. in your first fiddle, there is two 1's and tree 3's etc. I took your advice and structured my database as you suggested, but i need all url's to one post in ONE row.

Comment: What do you want as the desired result?  If you want the data to be displayed as a comma separated list, see my edit using `group_concat`.

Comment: Yes i looked around on google on it, but i dint get it to work. But your code helped me, Thanks alot my problem are solved.

Comment: A quick side question to this, if there are no images the post does not show at all. Thank you for your time

Comment: @RobinSandström If you want to return all posts even those without images, use a LEFT JOIN instead of the INNER JOIN.