# insert separated comma values into sql table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I have input values in the format of string (separated with comma).

```
customerID = "1,2,3,4,5"
```

How I can insert these value into the column `cutomerID` of temp customer table?

Comment: you could use a function returning a table containing integers e.g. [F_SplitAsIntTable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16993267/1699210)

Comment: Do you have a scripting language you can use to prepare a proper CSV file or SQL statements from this data?

Comment: Why don't you want to insert it as a string?

Comment: Below link might be helpful.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182668/how-to-split-comma-separated-text-in-mysql-stored-procedure

Comment: I think one of your tags is wrong. sql-server is abbreviation from Microsoft SQL Server. So please delete `mysql` or `sql-server` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Devart. This is one more alternate solution. Thanks all for helping me out.

```
    DECLARE @customerID varchar(max) = Null ;

  SET @customerID= '1,2,3,4,5'


     DECLARE @tempTble Table (
            customerID varchar(25) NULL);


while len(@customerID ) > 0
begin
  insert into @tempTble (customerID ) values(left(@customerID , charindex(',', @customerID +',')-1))
  set @customerID = stuff(@customerID , 1, charindex(',', @customerID +','), '')
end

select * from @tempTble
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this would be to save the values you want to insert as a CSV.

Then create a staging table: MyTable

Use the following TSQL to bulk insert the contents of your CSV. Make sure to change the file path. Finally, run the commented-out select statement to verify that your import was successful.

Note that the FIRSTROW argument specifies the number of the first row to load. The default is the first row in the specified data file. This value may need to be changed to fit the layout of your CSV.

> CREATE TABLE MyTable
>   (     CustomerID varchar(5) )
>
> SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
>
> DECLARE
>       @SQL varchar(2000),
>       @path varchar(500)
>
> SET   @path = 'C:\Users\VikrantShitole\Desktop\Test.csv'
>
> ```
> SET @SQL = "BULK INSERT MyTable"
>     + " FROM '" +   @path + "'"
>     + " WITH ("
>     + " FIELDTERMINATOR = ','"
>     + " ,ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'"
>     + " ,FIRSTROW = 2 "
>     + ")"
>
> EXEC(@SQL)
> ```
>
> -- SELECT * FROM MyTable

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I do not want to store values in CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @customerID VARCHAR(20)
SELECT @customerID = '1,2,3,4,5'

SELECT customerID = t.c.value('@s', 'INT')
FROM (
    SELECT field = CAST('<t s = "' + 
          REPLACE(
                 @customerID + ','
               , ','
               , '" /><t s = "') + '" />' AS XML) 
) d
CROSS APPLY field.nodes('/t') t(c)
WHERE t.c.value('@s', 'VARCHAR(5)') != ''
```

**Output:**

```
customerID
-----------
1
2
3
4
5
```